# passing parameter to JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I want to use a JQuery UI dialog but i can't. when I click different names, it loads the same page every time. The problem is there are too many hidden inputs so I just get the first value.

How can I do this dynamically?

**PHP**

```
while($s=mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
    $name=$["name"]; 
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <td class="dialog"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.dialog').click(function(){

    variable=$('.hidden').val();

    dialog1.load('page.php?do='+variable.dialog('open');

});
```

Basically I want to do this with JQuery:

```
  <td><a href="page.php?do=<?php echo $name; ?>" > Go</a></td>
```

Comment: Make your code properly formatted & separated into PHP & JS part (because, if I understand you correctly, these are separated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have anything inside a table that is outside the cell elements, so you have to put your `input` inside the `td`:

```
<td class="dialog">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
  <?php echo $name; ?>
</td>
```

As the input is inside the cell, you can easily find it without setting a class on it:

```
$('.dialog').click(function(){
  var variable = $('input', this).val();
  dialog1.load('page.php?do=' + variable).dialog('open');
});
```

(I am not sure about the second line inside the function. It was missing a parenthesis, so I added one where it looked like it was needed.)